# Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

why   Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment
      Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

        map:mapType="satellite"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

why   Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag fragment 
      Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment ?

Answer (score 18):

Remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from the `<fragment>` element, and consider moving `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` from the `<fragment>` element to the root element.

For example, this is valid:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:mapType="satellite"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: then "Unexpected namespace prefix "map" found for tag fragment"

Comment: still Unexpected namespace prefix **map** found for tag fragment

Comment: @Mr.Strolling: Ah, I think you are running into an Eclipse bug that I reported: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53283

Comment: Yeah,finally ,I use <include layout="@layout/XXX"/>,then it worked.

Comment: I always get that error whenever I edit the layout file containing my Map. Just go to Project > Clean. I guess using include helps you avoid the error whenever you want to edit the rest of the layout.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this is just a mis-lead Lint check error. You can remove it when, in Eclipse's *Problem view*, you right-click the line with the error, select the *Quick fix* option and select e.g. *Ignore Check for project*.

The error goes away, the project builds and the app runs perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```